# What is the format of public key?

Tags: certificate, base64, public-key, pki, asn.1

What is the format of public DSA key? And are all certificates are stored in base64?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a great deal of information and references on this page for the specifications.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm

Comment: there is no single word about FORMAT of public key

Comment: Ok, took a bit of searching through some PDF documents but here you go. Specifications Standard: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/DSA2_All.pdf   Another very interesting document: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the public key format used in a certificate?

Generally, a public key in a certificate is stored in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo field (cf. RFC 5280)

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
     subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The specifics for DSA can be found in [RFC 3370](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370#section-3.1). Usually the parameters of the AlgorithmIdentifier contain an instance of the Dss-Parms giving you p, k, g and the subjectPublicKey BIT STRING contains the public key y encoded as an DER-encoded INTEGER.

Concerning Base64: Strictly speaking certificates are *not* Base64-encoded but use an extended form of it, the PEM format, a plain text format which is the Base64 encoding of a X.509 certificate (RFC5280) enclosed between the lines

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" 
...
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

or

```
"-----BEGIN X509 CERTIFICATE----" 
...
"-----END X509 CERTIFICATE----".
```

The certificate itself is the DER encoding of the ASN.1 structure as described in RFC 5280. See [X.690](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) for details of DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules).

Most certificates are stored either in PEM format or directly in their raw DER-encoded form.